# Convert line breaks in php textarea

Tags: php, database

I have a kind of a guestbook on my page. It's just a common textarea like this:

```
echo '
<textarea name="msg"></textarea>';
```

and then I use a form to send me to the backend on submit:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$msg = $jinput->getString('msg');
$columns = array('message');
$values = array($db->quote($msg);
$query->insert($db->quoteName('guestbook'))->columns($db->quoteName($columns))->values(implode(',', $values));
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

But my problem is, that if the user write something like:

> Hey.
>
> This is a nice site.
>
> Bye for now!

The guestbook prints out:

> Hey. This is a nice site. Bye for now!

How can I get the line breaks from the user-inputs?

EDIT:
I echo the results like this:

```
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($results as $row) {
echo $msg;
}
```

Comment: Does your data saved in manner which is you wanted to show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how you are echoing the result, but have you tried wrapping it in `nl2br`?

Comment: Just edited my question :) Don't know how to wrap it but I'll take a look :)